# Htaccess: keeps asking for Login info

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, .htpasswd

I have a website and i have a problem with my Htaccess login. I put in the Username and password and it asks again and again.

here is my code:
.htaccess

```
AuthUserFile /webspace/httpdocs/****doman name*****/Admin/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Bitte Passwort eingeben"
AuthType Basic## Heading ##
<Limit GET>
require valid-user
</Limit>
```

.htpasswd

```
admin:$apr1$vo/xlPIv$p6BGvCBGW4L6vni7ejZ
```

thx for any help! (:

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same issue at our end. We were having Varnishd Cache installed on the server. Clearing the same did the trick.

In case you are using any caching mechanism like Varnish Cache or caching via nginx or apache cache. Try clearing the same on the server. It should do the trick.